# How to color a cell based on % of completion of another column % value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to color a column value based on % of completion of another column % value in excel?

Example :

[image: Excel sheet 1]

My requirement is that adding a color based on work done % value.
Suppose billing value >=50% of workdone cell value then add a green color to billing cell else red value.

I tried couple of way to add a new rule from conditional formatting but no luck.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Note: Both cells(work done and billing) value varies based on completion of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `=$F2/$E2>0.5` as rule.

The important part is to fix the columns ($F, $E) and have a relative row (2) as starting point.

You could also add a helper column that uses the same formula and then apply the rule to this column - sometimes this is easier to understand.